# Radionbutton output reset and border that's not showing up

Tags: python, tkinter

I am coding a python script that can display the buttons that I select to a label.

this program is containing 4 radiobutton and 1 label.

so far the problem of my program is that my program can not be repeated. Also I need to have a border surround the label.

I am using python 2.7 and I cannot post image because I don't have enough reputation

```
= Label(the_window, text = 'Null', fg = 'black',font = ('Times', 36), width = 8)
button.grid(row=2,column=1)
button.grid(row=3,column=1)
button.grid(row=2,column=2)
button.grid(row=3,column=2)
```

this is my setup

https://repl.it/BJcH

Comment: Yes, let's see the whole code. Incidentally, you can upload your image to imgur and post a link here. Only actually inlining images requires reputation.

Comment: Kevin my man, I rather send you the doc instead of putting it up on the site. I have my own reason, so how would you prefer me to send it to you?

Comment: No thanks. If the entire content of the question isn't publicly visible, then it won't be useful to future readers.

Comment: Then give me a minute, well is not like I can't put it up. is just messy

Comment: is on Kevin and thanks man appreciate your effort

Answer (score 1):

You can add a border to your label by specifying a `relief`:

```
direction_status = Label(the_window, text = 'Null', fg = 'black',
                         font = ('Times', 36), width = 8, relief=GROOVE)
```

Rather than using four BooleanVars as `value` attributes for your radio buttons, use a single IntVar. This will indicate to Tkinter that the radio buttons belong in the same group, and will ensure that only one can be selected at a time.

```
from Tkinter import *

# Create a window
the_window = Tk()

# Give the window a title
the_window.title('Compass')

##Label widget to display initial Compass's status
direction_status = Label(the_window, text = 'Null', fg = 'black',
                         font = ('Times', 36), width = 8)

## Function that define the label's text when radiobuttion is being selected
def update_the_window():
    if v.get() == 1:
        direction_status['text'] = 'NW'
    if v.get() == 2:
        direction_status['text'] = 'SW'
    if v.get() == 3:
        direction_status['text'] = 'NE'
    if v.get() == 4:
        direction_status['text'] = 'SE'

## Label Frame for direction_status
direction_status_frame = LabelFrame(the_window, relief = 'groove',
                             borderwidth = 2)


v = IntVar()
## 4 Buttons that change the status sorted by directions
NW_button = Radiobutton(text = 'North-West', variable = v,
                        value= 1, command=update_the_window, padx=20)
NW_button.pack(anchor=W)

SW_button = Radiobutton(text = 'South-West', variable = v,
                        value= 2, command = update_the_window, padx=20)
SW_button.pack(anchor=W)

NE_button = Radiobutton(text= 'North-East', variable = v,
                        value= 3, command=update_the_window, padx=20)
NE_button.pack(anchor=W)

SE_button = Radiobutton(text= 'South-East', variable = v,
                        value= 4, command=update_the_window, padx=20)
SE_button.pack(anchor=W)

## Grid geometry to put 4 radio buttons into the GUI
NW_button.grid(row=2,column=1)
SW_button.grid(row=3,column=1)
NE_button.grid(row=2,column=2)
SE_button.grid(row=3,column=2)

## Grid geometry manager to put the widget into the root window
margin = 5 ##pixels
direction_status.grid(padx=margin, pady=margin, row=1, column=1, columnspan=2)



#--------------------------------------------------------------------#

# Start the event loop to react to user inputs
the_window.mainloop()
```

You could also use a StringVar instead, which cuts down on the size of `update_the_window` somewhat.

```
from Tkinter import *

# Create a window
the_window = Tk()

# Give the window a title
the_window.title('Compass')

# PUT YOUR CODE HERE-------------------------------------------------#

##Label widget to display initial Compass's status
direction_status = Label(the_window, text = 'Null', fg = 'black',
                         font = ('Times', 36), width = 8)




## Function that define the label's text when radiobuttion is being selected
def update_the_window():
    direction_status['text'] = direction.get()

direction = StringVar()
direction.set("NW")
update_the_window()

## Label Frame for direction_status
direction_status_frame = LabelFrame(the_window, relief = 'groove',
                             borderwidth = 2)


## 4 Buttons that change the status sorted by directions
NW_button = Radiobutton(text = 'North-West', variable = direction,
                        value= "NW", command=update_the_window, padx=20)
NW_button.pack(anchor=W)

SW_button = Radiobutton(text = 'South-West', variable = direction,
                        value= "SW", command = update_the_window, padx=20)
SW_button.pack(anchor=W)

NE_button = Radiobutton(text= 'North-East', variable = direction,
                        value= "NE", command=update_the_window, padx=20)
NE_button.pack(anchor=W)

SE_button = Radiobutton(text= 'South-East', variable = direction,
                        value= "SE", command=update_the_window, padx=20)
SE_button.pack(anchor=W)

## Grid geometry to put 4 radio buttons into the GUI
NW_button.grid(row=2,column=1)
SW_button.grid(row=3,column=1)
NE_button.grid(row=2,column=2)
SE_button.grid(row=3,column=2)

## Grid geometry manager to put the widget into the root window
margin = 5 ##pixels
direction_status.grid(padx=margin, pady=margin, row=1, column=1, columnspan=2)



#--------------------------------------------------------------------#

# Start the event loop to react to user inputs
the_window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Solid effort Kevin, and as my post mention. There should be a border around the label area, I tried to use label frame, but there still nothing showing up? any suggestion?

Comment: Try setting the `relief` attribute of the label to something other than the default `FLAT`.

Comment: groove is the one I want however is just not doing anything whatsoever

Comment: You're doing it on the label and not the label frame, right?

Comment: in addition to `relief`, you need to make sure that `borderwidth` is non-zero. It might be zero depending on the platform, or depending on other code in the program.

Comment: well, it should be covering direction_status

Comment: is not zero Bryan, but the border line is just not showing up

Comment: solved it thanks guys, my solution is to cut off the frame and put it under label

Comment: Just curious, if I do Labelframe, does that meaning an area to put things in?